# Looking for a better approach on a mysql query for determining rank with a query

Tags: mysql

I'm reworking a mysql database I made for a timer a year ago. To give some background, its a timer for a racing mod which contains multiple maps that have multiple stages within each map. Heres a hypothetical example of the table running the query

```
SELECT SELECT *
FROM `records`
WHERE mapid = 3
AND stage = 1
ORDER BY TIME, DATE;

Records
-------------------------------------------------------------------
runId|userId |mapId|stage|  time | date 
3245 |  570  | 3   |  1  | 22.559|5/6/2013
4246 |  59   | 3   |  1  | 22.603|1/2/2014
1752 |  12   | 3   |  1  | 22.612|3/3/2013
1952 |  991  | 3   |  1  | 22.612|3/4/2013
1969 |  13   | 3   |  1  | 22.612|3/8/2013
4569 |  915  | 3   |  1  | 22.620|3/9/2014
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to determine a users rank for the stage on that specific course, which is somewhat difficult. The old method I've been using is just selecting the COUNT of times less than or equal to the users time, however that stops being reliable when times are completely equal(which is surprisingly common.) The only solution I've thought of so far is creating a ranks column, and using a stored procedure, and just using a cursor for the query to generate the table above to assign ranks via incrimentation, and just selecting the rank from there, but that seems a bit too last-resortish, and I'm trying to avoid that. So, any solutions/ideas on how I can approach this? Thanks.

(Also if times are equal, I want the newer time to be ranked below the older time. The reasoning for this is that there is a point system for top 10s, and multiple times the same ranks skews the system. Also an older time is usually more impressive then a newer time of the same value)

Or to make the question a bit more clear by example, how would I determine that runID 1952 on the table above is the 4th result, and not the third or fifth.

Comment: Please show the results that you want for your sample data.  What *do* you want to happen when the times are equal?  And, what *is* the query that you are using?

Comment: Sorry for making it a bit unclear, I put an example up to help explain what I mean.

Comment: It seems to me that you haven't defined completely enough what you mean by 'rank'. Why is it that two people who do the same thing in the same time, have different 'ranks'?

Comment: I added a bit of explanation for the reasoning at the bottom. It's a bit flawed, but I'm working with a point system I didn't make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a rank variable at zero and increment it by 1 for each row as if you were creating an index:

```
SET @rank := 0;

SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 `rank`
FROM records
WHERE mapid = 3
AND stage = 1
ORDER BY time, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

SELECT runId, userId, mapId, stage, time, date, (select count(distinct time) + 1 FROM records r2 WHERE r2.time < r1.time) as rank FROM records r1 ORDER BY rank, date